# Is it technically possible to intercept iOS audio to add DSP sound filtering?

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

I want to create an iPhone app that adds my custom sound processing to the current audio (like equalizing, reverb, dynamic compression and spatial processing).  I have good audio processing knowledge, but I can't find how to intercept audio from an iOS device to apply my filtering.

I am looking for a solution that would work with any source (any app) and any output (iPhone build-in speaker, wired headphones, bluetooth headset).

What I have explored so far:

1) Audio Units / Inter-App Audio. Unfortunately AU/IAA in only supported by limited music apps and I have not found a way to capture general audio.

2) Virtual AirPlay device.  Unfortunately selecting another output device would sink the sound out of the iPhone and the user would not be able to hear it anymore.

3) ReplayKit API. Unfortunately it seems incompatible with any AVPlayer media content.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in iOS.

Comment: What prevents your virtual AirPlay device from rerouting the audio to the previously selected "real" output device?

Comment: Could you provide code on how you created a virtual airplay device to route all phone sound to?

Comment: @Winston Du, I have explored the concept, but not done it unfortunately.